# Liquibase resource found in both Maven target and Maven repository

Tags: eclipse, maven, gwt, liquibase, flowable

I have Eclipse Maven GWT project and I added `flowable-form-engine` dependency that uses Liquibase. Liquibase is searching for changelog file `org/flowable/form/db/liquibase/flowable-form-db-changelog.xml` but finds two!

```
org.flowable.common.engine.api.FlowableException: Error initialising form data schema
    at org.flowable.form.engine.impl.db.FormDbSchemaManager.initSchema(FormDbSchemaManager.java:58)
    at org.flowable.form.engine.impl.cmd.SchemaOperationsFormEngineBuild.execute(SchemaOperationsFormEngineBuild.java:29)
    at org.flowable.form.engine.impl.cmd.SchemaOperationsFormEngineBuild.execute(SchemaOperationsFormEngineBuild.java:24)
    at org.flowable.common.engine.impl.interceptor.DefaultCommandInvoker.execute(DefaultCommandInvoker.java:10)
    at org.flowable.common.engine.impl.interceptor.TransactionContextInterceptor.execute(TransactionContextInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.flowable.common.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:71)
    at org.flowable.common.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:30)
    at org.flowable.common.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:56)
    at org.flowable.form.engine.impl.FormEngineImpl.<init>(FormEngineImpl.java:45)
    at org.flowable.form.engine.FormEngineConfiguration.buildFormEngine(FormEngineConfiguration.java:172)
    at org.flowable.form.engine.configurator.FormEngineConfigurator.initFormEngine(FormEngineConfigurator.java:83)
    at org.flowable.form.engine.configurator.FormEngineConfigurator.configure(FormEngineConfigurator.java:63)
    at org.flowable.common.engine.impl.AbstractEngineConfiguration.configuratorsAfterInit(AbstractEngineConfiguration.java:859)
    at org.flowable.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.init(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.java:985)
    at org.flowable.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.buildProcessEngine(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.java:887)
    at sk.dominanz.coarui.server.services.WorkflowServiceAdditional.<clinit>(WorkflowServiceAdditional.java:64)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: Error Reading Migration File: Found 2 files that match org/flowable/form/db/liquibase/flowable-form-db-changelog.xml
    at liquibase.parser.core.xml.XMLChangeLogSAXParser.parseToNode(XMLChangeLogSAXParser.java:118)
    at liquibase.parser.core.xml.AbstractChangeLogParser.parse(AbstractChangeLogParser.java:15)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.getDatabaseChangeLog(Liquibase.java:217)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:190)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:179)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:175)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:168)
    at org.flowable.form.engine.impl.db.FormDbSchemaManager.initSchema(FormDbSchemaManager.java:52)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Found 2 files that match org/flowable/form/db/liquibase/flowable-form-db-changelog.xml
    at liquibase.util.StreamUtil.singleInputStream(StreamUtil.java:206)
    at liquibase.parser.core.xml.XMLChangeLogSAXParser.parseToNode(XMLChangeLogSAXParser.java:71)
    ... 55 more
```

So I debugged it and it finds one resource from target directory:

```
jar:file:/C:/work/git/coarui/target/Main-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/flowable-form-engine-6.4.0.jar!/org/flowable/form/db/liquibase/flowable-form-db-changelog.xml
```

and other resource from maven repository:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/Piro/.m2/repository/org/flowable/flowable-form-engine/6.4.0/flowable-form-engine-6.4.0.jar!/org/flowable/form/db/liquibase/flowable-form-db-changelog.xml
```

Is there a way to ignore one of them, or is my build path or dependency definition wrong?

My build path contains:

- src/main/java sources
- src/test/java sources
- JRE System library
- Maven dependencies (in C:/Users/Piro/.m2/repository...)
- JUnit4

Looking at source code resources are read `classLoader.getResources(path);` where class loader is jetty class loader `JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload$WebAppClassLoaderExtension`.

In my run/debug configuration I have classpath similar to build path plus GWT library `gwt-dev-2.8.1.jar - C:\Users\Piro\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-dev\2.8.1`

In `pom.xml` dependency is defined as:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.flowable</groupId>
  <artifactId>flowable-form-engine-configurator</artifactId>
  <version>${flowableVersion}</version>
</dependency>
```

Maven GWT plugin `groupId=net.ltgt.gwt.maven, artifactId=gwt-maven-plugin` has configuration parameter `classpathScope` but I tested `<classpathScope>compile+runtime</classpathScope>`, `<classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>` and `<classpathScope>runtime</classpathScope>` and the same error occurs.

Searching the internet I found similar posts on flowable forum ([1](https://forum.flowable.org/t/form-engine-error/1156), [2](https://forum.flowable.org/t/form-engine-not-initialized-error/1143/2)) but no solution is provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that for some reason your `.m2` is in the classpath. If it really makes sense to you then you can try to use `<scope>provided</scope>` in a pom where you declare dependency to `flowable-form-engine-configurator`. However you may decide to exclude `.m2` from classpath which is better I think.

Answer (score 3):

This generally happens when you mix client and server code in the same Maven module, and given how GWT works there's no (easy) around that, besides splitting your code in separate client and server (and possibly shared) Maven modules.

You can have a look at https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes for examples (disclaimer: I'm the author, but also a member of GWT's Steering Committee)